# What's the difference between wrapping a try-finally block with a try-except block and vice versa?

Tags: delphi, exception

Are there any practical difference between the two coding patterns in Delphi:

**Version 1**

```
try
  try
    {Do something}
  finally
    {Do tidy up}
  end
except
  {Handle exception}
end;
```

**Version 2**

```
try
  try
    {Do something}
  except
    {Handle exception}
  end
finally
  {Do tidy up}
end;
```

Comment: As an aside, I found a rather wacky x64 bug related to finally blocks that mean they can get called twice!  http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=108457

Comment: The code does not show where a protected resource is allocated (SomeObject.Create). Is it in the `do something` part or earlier?

Comment: It's unfortunate that `finally` blocks and `except` blocks are both introduced with the same `try` keyword because they're otherwise orthogonal concepts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi Exception Handling - How to clean up properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473575/delphi-exception-handling-how-to-clean-up-properly)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two differences:

1. The relative order in which the except and finally blocks execute differs. In version 1, the finally executes before the except. In version 2 the excecution order is reversed.
2. In version 1, if the finally block raises, then it will be handled by the except block. In version 2, if the finally block raises, then it will be handled by the next containing exception handler, i.e. outside this code.

Usually you aren't concerned about finally blocks that raise. You simply don't expect that to happen and if it does, something is probably very broken.

So the difference that counts is whether the finally runs before the exception handler, or vice versa. Sometimes it doesn't matter, but it often does make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `try..except` below lines executed.

```
Resource := TAbstractResource.Create;
try
  Resource.DoSomeThing;
except
  On E:Exception Do 
   HandleException(E);
end;
FreeAndNil(Resource);
```

Comment: I cannot see how this relates to the question, or indeed anything at all. What's more, best practise is to use finally to protect resources and let exceptions float to higher level code.

Comment: I think the answerer meant if you handle any exception in `except` block you need not `finally` block.

Comment: @Serg OK, that would make sense. However, I'd still reject this code if it was ever put before me. Try/finally is how to protect resources and when I see try/finally, I know what it means. When I don't see it I have to think.

Comment: @Serg, this code could still be wrong, though, since it only handles descendants of `Exception`, which doesn't include *all* things that might be thrown. In addition, it also doesn't handle the case when `HandleException` throws something of its own.

Comment: @Rob What else can be thrown that is not an Exception?

Comment: @Awmross, TStringList, TFont, TForm, you name it. Any descendant of TObject can be thrown. That's why ExceptObject returns the type it does.